# How to make a video full screen using an Exoplayer without stretching it

Tags: android, android-video-player, exoplayer

I'm using an ExoPlayer to show videos, currently I just maintain the aspect ratio as default but this isn't ideal as I want the videos full screen.

```
        for (Listener listener : mListeners) {
        listener.onVideoSizeChanged(width, height, pixelWidthHeightRatio);
    }
```

I've tried setting the video to take the entire width of the screen however this just stretches and distorts the video. Any idea how to scale the video up while maintain its height:width ratio?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this lines

```
 this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //will hide the status bar
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); //will rotate the screen
```